# MongoDB connection with Robomong

Tags: node.js, windows

I have created a database in mongodbv3.2 on openshift v3.2 and the query is how do i connect to that mongodb using robomongo can any one explain the procedure to connect to the mongodb

Comment: ...You just fill in the fields in the RoboMongo UI? What are you stuck on exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question when I was trying to expose an `mysql` service to be consumed by an external resource. I got it done in v3.3 so I'm not really sure if this applies to 3.2 but check out [Ingress Ports](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/admin_guide/tcp_ingress_external_ports.html) in the official docs.